# AngularJS - Can't sum up properties on Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angular code sitting in an angular controller:

Code:

```
$scope.orangeCrate.italian = {
    "description": "Annual",
    "payer": "farmer",
    "farmerCost": 0,
    "ownerCost": 21
};

$scope.orangeCrate.portugal = {
    "description": "Annual",
    "payer": "owner",
    "farmerCost": 6.5,
    "ownerCost": 0
};

$scope.orangeCrate.total = {
    "farmerCost": $scope.orangeCrate.italian.farmerCost + $scope.orangeCrate.portugal.farmerCost,
    "ownerCost": $scope.orangeCrate.italian.ownerCost + $scope.orangeCrate.portugal.ownerCost,
};
```

When I try and print out the value inside `$scope.orangeCrate.total.farmerCost` onto my view, I get nothing, even though I should be getting `6.5`!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `$scope.orangeCrate` exist before you assign to its `italian` and `portugal` properties (if not then JavaScript will throw an error)? How are you referencing the value inside the view? It seems to work here... http://jsfiddle.net/685SW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do(sorry for the "poor" answer..I'm in a hurry):

```
$scope.orangeCrate = {
    "italian": {
        "description": "Annual",
            "payer": "farmer",
            "farmerCost": 0,
            "ownerCost": 21
    },
        "portugal": {
        "description": "Annual",
            "payer": "owner",
            "farmerCost": 6.5,
            "ownerCost": 0
    }
};
$scope.orangeCrate.total = {
    "farmerCost": $scope.orangeCrate.italian.farmerCost + $scope.orangeCrate.portugal.farmerCost,
        "ownerCost": $scope.orangeCrate.italian.ownerCost + $scope.orangeCrate.portugal.ownerCost,
};
```